# java code for checking if jar file are signed or not

Tags: java, jar, jar-signing

I have a question regarding verifying if a `.jar` file is signed or not.

How can I check this with standard java code, not using the `jarsigner`, etc.?

Comment: [Class.getSigners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSigners%28%29).

Comment: is this similar to getCodeSigners() from the class JarEntry?

Comment: JarEntry.getCodeSigners seems more appropiate, +1. Also Class.getSigners yields an Object.

Comment: Or, for those of you, like me, who landed here after googling how to do this _with_ `jarsigner`, just execute `jarsigner -verify thejar.jar`

Comment: `jarsigner` does not merely check if the JAR is signed or not. It will verify the signatures are correct and were generated with a known/installed key. I found that this had massive performance penalties versus scanning the manifest as Evgeniy's answer suggests.

Answer (score 8):

If you simply want to check if jar is signed or not check MANIFEST.MF attributes with JarFile, there should be entries like this for each file

```
Name: sun/plugin/AppletViewer$2.class
SHA-256-Digest: VAPu2ppyO3MeFiJBHcCmusw+59pL4pRg9n2aKWyHnS0=
```

Comment: in a given folder I want to iterate over all .jar files and check which one are signed and which one are not signed. I dont know if checking for .SF file should be enough

Comment: I suggested testing MANIFEST.MF because its easy to do, JareFile has convinient methods to read MANIFEST attributes

Comment: yes, but the MANIFEST file is always there, independent if the .jar file is signed or not